# Bot plays same audio for joining and leaving the channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

my Bot is playing the same audio File for joining and leaving the Voice Channel and i dont know how to solve it:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel
    const voiceChannel = client.channels.cache.get('807305239941480543')
    if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined && oldMember.member.user.bot === false && newMember.member.user.bot === false) {
        voiceChannel.join().then(connection => { connection.play("./a.mp3").on("finish", () => connection.disconnect())
        }); 
  
    } else if(newUserChannel === undefined && oldMember.member.user.bot === false && newMember.member.user.bot === false){
        voiceChannel.join().then(connection => { connection.play("./b.mp3").on("finish", () => connection.disconnect())
            });
  
    }
  })
```

I dont get any error and the Bot works but the Bot is playing the audio file ./b.mp3 everytime and not the audio ./a.mp3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already on the right track but you're overthinking the `if` statement.

First off, when the [`voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) event is triggered, the parameters available are [`voiceStates`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) so we'll use `oldState` and `newState` in this code.

You have the right idea when you check if the user is a bot but you can do that in a separate check.

```
if (oldState.member.user.bot) return;
```

Now that we know a user is joining/leaving we can differentiate, however we need to check three cases:

1. a user joins a new channel, here case A
2. a user leaves a channel, here case B
3. a user switches channels, here case C

A joining is indicated if `oldState.channelID` is either `null` or `undefined`.

```
oldState.channelID === null || typeof oldState.channelID == 'undefined'
```

A leaving is indicated if `newState.channelID` is either `null` or `undefined`.

```
newState.channelID === null || typeof newState.channelID == 'undefined'
```

A switching is indicated if neither of the above fit which we simply cover with `else`.

Since I don't have your MP3 files I simply `console.log()` a "PLAYING (A/B/C)" which you need  to switch out for your audiofiles.

The entire `voiceStateUpdate` looks like this:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    if (oldState.member.user.bot) return;
    const voiceChannel = client.channels.cache.get('807305239941480543');

    if (oldState.channelID === null || typeof oldState.channelID == 'undefined') {
        voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            console.log("PLAYING (A)");
            connection.disconnect();
        });
    } else if (newState.channelID === null || typeof newState.channelID == 'undefined') {
        voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            console.log("PLAYING (B)");
            connection.disconnect();
        });
    } else {
        voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            console.log("PLAYING (C)");
            connection.disconnect();
        });
    }
})
```

;